# Bluetooth module HC05 + Bluetooth my computer + C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am working with Bluetooth. I use STM32F4xx kit to send data  to module Bluetooth HC05 and I use Bluetooth on my computer to receive the data. Everything is ok if i send and receive a byte.
However when I send a frame contain: the first index, 10 bytes data and the end index (12 bytes in total), the series port on my computer receive the wrong data. For example, i send a string like *1234500000~, and my series port on my computer receives like 123450000~ or 000~000~.
I use C# to create a windows form to exchange data.

here are my code on C#:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
            c = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            Connect_bt.Text = c;
            label19.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Length);
            a[n] = serialPort1.ReadByte();
            if (n > 13)
            {
                n = 0;
                label18.Text = "0";
            }
            n++; label18.Text = label18.Text  + Convert.ToString(a[n]);   
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIOAk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3p8c.png)